# Can I skip or inactive any ODI components from packages while executing in ODI 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

I would like to deactivate or skip or inactivate any one of a component in the ODI package while executing, without deleting the desired component in ODI 11g.

As i have some SMTP server issue, i wanted to skip the SentEmail component as it is getting failed and throws the exception. Without deleting this sent email step, i would like to skip this step and run the subsequent steps to complete the execution of the package. Once SMTP server is live, i will revert the changes done to the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could temporarly draw an OK line (green) going from the step before the SendEmail step to the step after it, bypass the erroneous step.

But instead of doing that, my recommendation would rather be to add a KO line (red) between the SendEmail step and the next one. That means that the next step would be executed even if the SendEmail fails.

Comment: Yes, i bypassed the email step by drawing OK line between the step before email and step after it. It worked. Thank you!